# List merge commits where once of the ancestors touched a certain file

Tags: git, git-log

I want to list only merge commits through which a given file actually made it into the current branch. As an example:

```
-A--B----C-------D--E------F----G--------H---
  \   \---P--Q--/    \---X--Y--/        /
   \-----------------------------M-----/
```

Let's say P and Y were the only commits that modified abc.txt. In this case, how do I get git log to list only D and G? Note that D and G did not actually touch abc.txt directly: they were just merge commits that had ancestors that touched abc.txt.

I tried:

```
git log --merges -m --name-only --follow abc.txt
```

Unfortunately, this includes H as well, since H had once ancestor (G) that touched (via Y) abc.txt.

(Note: [List merge commits affecting a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10180751/list-merge-commits-affecting-a-file) asks a different question: it asks which merge commits (not their ancestors, but the merge commit itself) actually touched abc.txt.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, at least not directly.  (I think—this is based on the fact that `--simplify-merges` is, apparently, not doing what you want.  Normally it seems like it would do what you want.  Note that you would need both `--simplify-merges` *and* `--merges` here; and you will use `--simplify-merges` but not `--merges` in the `git rev-list` below, in the "first" step.)

> Note that D and G did not actually touch abc.txt directly: they were just merge commits that had ancestors that touched abc.txt.

Well, yes and no.  Like any commit in Git, a merge commit has a tree and some parent(s).  Commits D and G, being merges, have at least two parent commits.  Each parent also has a tree, so we can diff (or have Git diff) D^1 (i.e., C) vs D, and D^2 (i.e., Q) vs D.  One of those two—the first, if I have the two parents ordered correctly—will show a change to `abc.txt`.  We can diff each of G^1 and G^2 against G in the same manner and get the same effect.  But I think we all know what you mean: the change we discover in this manner exists *because of* some earlier commit.

But this is true for H as well!  Diffing H^2 (aka M) vs H shows a change to this same file.  This change is brought about through G, the same way G's change is brought about through Y.  So then the question becomes: why should we count G, yet not count H?

I *think* the reason we should count G but not H here is that the ancestor(s)—namely Y—that "brought about" the change have a "downstream" commit, namely G, that is a merge, that we would like to claim "absorbs" the change.

(According to this same logic, if M made a change to `abc.txt` too, we would then like to include H in our set after all.)

If that reasoning is correct, that suggests an algorithm for finding the merges you care about:

- First, find all merges where the file changes in any way.  This selects all of D, G, and H.
- Second, for each such merge, find its parents (there are at least two). If the merge commit version of `abc.txt` differs from *both* parent versions, mark the merge as "definitely included" in the set: we brought in changes from "both sides" and/or this is an "evil merge" (it introduces changes that were not made in either parent-fork).  If not, though, mark the merge as "potentially removable".
- Last, iterate through all "potentially removable" merges, in "most parent-y" order (do all parents before any children: you'll get this naturally out of the appropriate `git rev-list --topo-order --reverse` in the first step, or you can get the list in the other order and then work in reverse).  Any commit marked "definitely keep" stays; any commit marked "maybe keep, maybe removable, depending on parent #N" stays *unless* it has a kept parent merge that has the *same* `abc.txt` as the parent-in-that-direction; and any marked "maybe keep, maybe removable" gets removed when it has a kept parent-in-that-direction that does have the same `abc.txt`.

  (I'm not sure off-hand how to modify this for octopus merges so I'll leave thinking about that to you.)

Comment: Thanks, this helps! Octopus merges won't occur in my particular use case either.